# OpenSSL: how to encrypt new message with same key without EVP_EncryptInit_ex() again?

Tags: openssl, aes

Using OpenSSL cryptographic library, I need to encrypt multiple messages using the same key. Using AES-128-CBC as an example.

After getting an `EVP_CIPHER_CTX`, the standard scenario is:

- `EVP_EncryptInit_ex()`
- `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding()` (no padding in my case, always a multiple of 16 bytes)
- `EVP_EncryptUpdate()`
- `EVP_EncryptFinal_ex()`

If we do this, it works but it is horribly inefficient because calling `EVP_EncryptInit_ex()` for each message recomputes the intermediate keys (in the case of AES) each time, even though the key does not change. With other crypto libraries, you can compute the intermediate keys only once and use the same key context for all messages as long as you use the same key.

With OpenSSL, it does not work in the general case. In practice, it works with AES-128-ECB because there is no IV and no chaining, but it does not work with AES-128-CBC. It seems that `EVP_EncryptFinal_ex()` is not really "final" and the last cipher block remains as IV. See a sample test program below.

How would you reset the `EVP_CIPHER_CTX` without clearing the intermediate keys, using the same key, and ideally set a new IV?

Not doing this is awfully slow, 12 times slower. Using the same test program as base, looping 1 million times on the encrypt operation below, 32 bytes message, AES-128-CBC, takes 16 ms when the key is scheduled once before the loop (but does not work as expected) and 194 ms when we reschedule it in each iteration. The CPU is an Intel Core i7-13700H.

There must be something obvious I missed. I cannot find anything online about this.

Currently, I use AES-128-ECB on each block and do the chaining by hand. It is much faster than using AES-128-CBC and reschedule the key for each message. Not really ideal.

OpenSSL version is 3.0.10 on Ubuntu 23.10.

Sample source code to test:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>

// AES-128-CBC test vector (no padding):
static const uint8_t key[] = {0x2A, 0x98, 0xF5, 0xF7, 0x79, 0x99, 0x15, 0x24, 0x0B, 0xBA, 0xAA, 0x42, 0x2A, 0x6B, 0x4C, 0x8E};
static const uint8_t iv[]  = {0x4A, 0x28, 0x80, 0xC6, 0x44, 0x97, 0x9C, 0x8F, 0xD2, 0xBB, 0xF8, 0xD0, 0xCA, 0xB2, 0x10, 0x5F};
static const uint8_t pt[]  = {0xB7, 0x3D, 0x23, 0xC6, 0x3B, 0x13, 0xE4, 0x3A, 0x31, 0x15, 0x13, 0x42, 0x75, 0xB7, 0xAC, 0xB8,
                              0x18, 0xE0, 0x90, 0xFA, 0x57, 0x62, 0xA3, 0xF6, 0xE7, 0x09, 0x6B, 0xAB, 0x20, 0x97, 0x71, 0xA2};
static const uint8_t ct[]  = {0xD5, 0xED, 0xF0, 0xE1, 0xBA, 0x3E, 0x2D, 0x33, 0xDB, 0xF0, 0xDA, 0xC0, 0xA7, 0x34, 0x72, 0xD6,
                              0x69, 0x4F, 0x62, 0x35, 0xC9, 0xBA, 0xE9, 0xB4, 0x82, 0x22, 0x17, 0xF5, 0xE3, 0xA8, 0x8B, 0xEC};

static void check(int cond)
{
    if (!cond) {
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

int main()
{
    ERR_load_crypto_strings();
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();

    EVP_CIPHER* algo = EVP_CIPHER_fetch(NULL, "AES-128-CBC", NULL);
    check(algo != NULL);

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX* ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
    check(algo != NULL);

    uint8_t data[sizeof(ct)];
    int len, final;

    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        // Doesn't work if called only once, before the loop.
        check(EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, algo, NULL, key, iv) == 1);
        check(EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding(ctx, 0) == 1);

        check(EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, data, &len, pt, sizeof(pt)) == 1);
        check(EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx, data + len, &final) == 1);
        printf("encrypt #%d: %s\n", i, len + final == sizeof(ct) && memcmp(data, ct, sizeof(ct)) == 0 ? "passed" : "FAILED");
    }

    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
    EVP_CIPHER_free(algo);
    EVP_cleanup();
    ERR_free_strings();
}
```

Comment: In each loop after the first, and optionally the first (which may make the code cleaner),  call `EncryptInit*` with `cipher` and `key` NULL and `iv` as desired. Note however that using the same key and IV for different encryptions, or at least for encryption of different plaintexts, is not considered fully secure, though it is not nearly as bad for CBC as for some other modes. That is offtopic here; see security.SX.

Comment: Thanks a lot @dave_thompson_085! It works. I already tried something similar, calling `EVP_EncryptInit_ex` with key being NULL and got a segmentation fault. I did not notice that it was necessary to set cipher to NULL as well.

Comment: And concerning the security of reusing the IV, I know. However, there are some standardized protocols in Digital TV such as DVS042 and DVB-CISSA where encryption occurs "in place", replacing the plain data with the same number of bytes. There is no room for a new IV per message and the IV is hard-coded in the standard. Yes, I know...